# Display Multiple Notes on Same Date of Calender

Tags: asp.net

I want to display calendar with some notes/events which i stored in database.
In some date more than one notes are added.

Now when page is load i want that all in my calendar control.

I done that BUT It displays only one(1st entered) note in the calendar although i saved more than one notes on that same DATE.

It looks like below image..
[image]

In this Image On Date 7 i added 2 Notes but it displays only one...

My code is as below...

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

{

    public static ArrayList MyColllection;

    //Structure

    public struct My_Date

    {

        public DateTime Cal_Date;

        public string Cal_Type;

        public string Cal_Title;

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)

        {

            MyColllection = Get_Event();

        }

    }

    public ArrayList Get_Event()

    {

        SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

        SqlCommand myComd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Cal_Event",myCon);

        SqlDataReader myDataReader;

        try

        {

            myCon.Open();

            myDataReader = myComd.ExecuteReader();

            MyColllection = new ArrayList();

            My_Date temp;

            //Iterate through the data reader

            while(myDataReader.Read())

            {

                temp.Cal_Title = myDataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();

                temp.Cal_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(myDataReader.GetValue(2));

                temp.Cal_Type = myDataReader.GetValue(3).ToString();

                MyColllection.Add(temp);

            }

        }

        catch

        {}

        finally

        {

            myCon.Close();

        }

        return MyColllection;

    }

    public void Calendar1_DayRender(object o, DayRenderEventArgs e)

    {

        string FontColor;

        string compDate = "01/01/1900"; // Date to compare initially

        DateTime DayVal = Convert.ToDateTime(compDate);

        bool mItemDay = false;

        bool dayTextChanged = false;

        StringBuilder strTemp = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (My_Date temp_dt in MyColllection)

        {

            if ("01/01/1900" != temp_dt.Cal_Date.ToShortDateString())

            {

                if (dayTextChanged == true)

                {

                    break;

                }

                mItemDay = false;

                DayVal = temp_dt.Cal_Date;

            }

            else

            {

                mItemDay = true;

            }

            if (e.Day.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(temp_dt.Cal_Date.ToString("d")))

            {

                switch (temp_dt.Cal_Type)

                {

                    case "1" :

                        FontColor = "Blue";

                        break;

                    case "2":

                        FontColor = "Red";

                        break;

                    default:

                        FontColor = "Black";

                        break;

                }

                if (mItemDay == false)

                {

                    strTemp = new StringBuilder();

                }

                else

                {

                    strTemp.Append("<br>");

                }

                strTemp.Append("<span style='font-family:verdana;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;color'");

                strTemp.Append(FontColor);

                strTemp.Append("'><br>");

                strTemp.Append(temp_dt.Cal_Title.ToString());

                strTemp.Append("</span>");

                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

                dayTextChanged = true;

            }

        }

        if (dayTextChanged == true)

        {

            e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strTemp.ToString()));

        }

    }

}
```

So I need to display multiple Notes on same day...

So How can I do this??

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendars are basically date pickers and using them to display data is one of the most common mistakes people make. Use a ListView to display your data/events; calendars were never meant for that.

At some stage the calendar cells are going to stretch as events are added for the same day, breaking the entire display. And if you try to set a limit, then people are going to complain and start asking why other events are listed and theirs aren't, etc.

In your code, you're basically swallowing the exception instead of handling it. Comment out the try-catch-finally (leave the Close()) and check what error you get then :)